# Play Framework: How to pass the current request to a body parser

Tags: scala, playframework

I've implemented a `SecureAction` for my controller like this:

```
class SecureRequest[A](
  val token: Token,
  request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {
  ...
}

class SecureAction[T <: Controller : TypeTag] private(
  private val methodName: String,
  private val tokenTypes: Seq[TokenType]) extends ActionBuilder[SecureRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: SecureRequest[A] => Future[Result]) = {
    ...
  }
}

def saveFile = SecureAction.async(fsBodyParser) { implicit request =>

  // code here not executed if current user has not required privileges
  ...
}
```

Everything works fine... except that even if the request is **NOT** authorized `fsBodyParser` gets still invoked and the multipart file saved in the database.

The implicit `request` object contains security rules... so would it be possible to pass somehow the request to the body parser?

**EDIT**

This is my body parser...

```
fsBodyParser()(
  implicit fsService: FsServiceComponent#FsService
): BodyParser[MultipartFormData[Future[MetaFile]]] = {
  import BodyParsers.parse._

  multipartFormData(
    Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
        fsService.iteratee(filename, contentType)
    }
  ) 
}
```

I probably need a method that can be invoked from the body of the action so that security is not by-passed. It's not clear to me who the body signature should look like:

```
def saveFile = SecureAction.async(fsBodyParser) { implicit request =>

  // how should the signature of this method look like???
  parseMultpart(request.body  ???)

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BodyParser[T]` is a function from `RequestHeader` to `Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, A]]`, so it does have access to the request header when being executed.

Although I would say that the intent of the `Request => Future[Result]` pipeline in *Play!* is for the `BodyParser` to just transform the incoming body, not take action on the body. I would suggest that you do not store the file at the bodyParser stage, but only once your `SecureAction` is invoked and retrieves the body from the request.

Comment: ... but how do I manage things in case of MultipartFormData? I don't want to let Play save incoming data to a temporary file (my `fsBodyParser` stores incoming data into MongoDB directly).

Comment: You could probably define it as `BodyParser[Iterratee[Array[Byte]]`, i.e. the same datatype that comes into it, letting you pipe the data into your SecureAction, where you can consume it and send it to MongoDB. Not sure of the pipeing semantics of Iteratee

Comment: It is not clear to me how the signature of such a method should be - see my updated question. Shall I create a method that takes the body as an input? I'm starting to be lost ;-)

Comment: Not having dealt with Multipart myself, I'd have to dig a bit deeper into Multipart body parsing and how piping from the parser to the Action might work. Going to tempfiles, while not as ideal as streaming straight into MongoDB might be significantly simpler, at least for the time being

Comment: OK, tx anyway for your great support ;-)